# What do you call a person who makes a booking himself via an online service, for himself and/or a group of persons including himself?

Tags: single-word-requests

As a non-native english speaker, I have always used "booker" so far, but recently found out that it might not be correct.

Context: hotels, plane tickets, ...

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! Would a person booking plane tickets online be an agent in the eyes of the airline?

Comment: Check the answer, just added a few more information to clarify.

Comment: Are you talking about someone who makes a booking but is not otherwise involved or the person who makes a booking for themselves and possibly a group of others?

Comment: I am talking about a person that makes a booking himself via an online service, for himself and/or a group of persons including himself

Comment: Then, you need to edit your question that is not clear. Booker has a negative connotation.

Comment: This is totally something else. Definitely not an agent. Deleting answer. So the person who does the booking for himself and the group he is in then isn't he just a traveler? Or He can act like an agent among her friends humorously?

Comment: I wouldn't call that person a traveler as he could also book a room in a hotel close to his home for example.

Comment: Not sure how Booker has a negative connotation. It and bookie are slang for bookmaker; and are a very different part of the process, as they run a book.
Whereas an agent runs a book for booking travellers with airlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about someone who *takes* the booking on behalf of someone or an organisation else they would be the **agent** as in travel agent or booking agent also if they *make* a booking for someone else they can be referred to as that persons agent or representative as in the phase "my secretary acted as my representative in making this booking" for example.

If you are talking about someone who made a booking for themselves *only* or possibly themselves and immediate family then you would commonly refer to them as the **customer**.

If you are talking about someone who made the booking on behalf of a group of which they are a part then they would be the **primary** or **organiser**. In this case you might say something like "I acted as the primary in making the booking for our book club dinner" or "I was the organiser for our company trip to the theatre" either way it would be understood that you were the one that made the booking for everybody.

Comment: Thanks, really good answer I think. The word **organiser** makes a lot of sense.